# Restart program unelevated

Tags: c#, uac, elevation, elevated-privileges

For some reason, my C# program needs to restart with elevated privileges. I use the following code to achieve it:

```
private static void RestartForPermissionsFix()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processInfo.FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

    Process.Start(processInfo);
}
```

This works great.

After I "fix my privileges", I want to restart the program **unelevated**. I tried the same as above without the "runas", but it does not work. I assume the process being started from an elevated process automatically gets elevated. Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to launch a process at medium integrity from a high integrity process, I believe you would have to get the current process token using [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295.aspx), duplicate it, remove the high integrity SID from the token using [`SetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379591.aspx), and then use that token to create the new process using [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx). This would be similar to [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx), except rather than add the low integrity SID you'd have to remove the high integrity one. Note: I haven't tested this, so I'm not 100% sure it would work.

I suggest you leave the original unelevated process running, and have it wait for its elevated counterpart to finish (e.g. using [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)). Once that finishes, it can continue unelevated as before. This would be a lot easier and more foolproof.

Comment: I second the idea of letting the first (unelevated) process running and resume it when the second (elevated) process has finished (you could use `Process.WaitForExit()`).

Comment: Thanks sven. Of course your suggestion is a lot simpler. I refactored my program a little bit so that there's no problem having two instances running in parallel.

Comment: @coffee_machine: One additional bit of info: one of the reasons why re-launching unelevated would be a bad idea is if the user is an actual limited user. In that case elevation executes the process in a different account and you'd have to somehow figure out what the original account was to launch the process using those credentials. I myself run in that configuration.

Comment: `elevation executes the process in a different account` - Raymond [explains what to do in this situation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/11/18/10468726.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an application that I wanted to update automatically (The update program requires elevated privileges).

What I did was creating an external *.exe* that would start my updater program with elevated privileges, wait for it to exit, then restart my application with normal privileges.

I then embedded this *.exe* in my main application, and start this *.exe* just before leaving my application when I update it.