# How to start a new process without administrator privileges from a process with administrator privileges?

Tags: c#, windows, administrator

I am creating an automatic updater for an application. The application is started by the user, and runs without administrator privileges. The autoupdater is started with administrator privileges, and kills the application before it downloads the new files.

The problem comes when I want to start the updated application after the autoupdater is finished. If I use regular System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file), the application starts with administrator privileges too, and it *has* to run on the current user to work as intended.

So, how can I make the autoupdater start the application as the current user instead of the administrator?

I have tried using the following:

```
var pSI = new ProcessStartInfo() { 
    UseShellExecute = false, 
    UserName = Environment.UserName, 
    FileName = file 
};
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pSI);
```

But this throws the error "Invalid user name or password". I have checked that the username is correct, and I understand that the password probably is invalid, as I have not included it. But it is not an option to ask the user to input his/her password, since the entire reason to start the application automatically is to make it easier for the user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735713/622391) describes an approach where you take a copy of the current process token, remove the high integrity SID using `SetTokenInformation`, then start the new process with the modified token using `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Comment: I know this is old, but I found a really good approach here that works better for me than the answer on this post. CreateProcessWithTokenW call failed for me. This works: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCreateLowIntegrityProcess-d7cb5e4d/sourcecode?fileId=52580&pathId=1953311234

Comment: C++ question corresponding to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948064/how-to-launch-non-elevated-administrator-process-from-elevated-administrator-con

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve cannot be done very easily and is not supported. However, it is possible using a modicum of hacking. Aaron Margosis wrote an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx) describing one technique.

To quote the pertinent section, you will need to carry out these steps:

> 1. Enable the SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in your current token
> 2. Get an HWND representing the desktop shell (GetShellWindow)
> 3. Get the Process ID (PID) of the process associated with that window (GetWindowThreadProcessId)
> 4. Open that process (OpenProcess)
> 5. Get the access token from that process (OpenProcessToken)
> 6. Make a primary token with that token (DuplicateTokenEx)
> 7. Start the new process with that primary token (CreateProcessWithTokenW)

The article contains a download link for some demo C++ source from which it should be simple enough to translate to C#.

Comment: The link you gave me worked great! I don't know c++ I will try to convert that code to c#. I will accept your answer as soon as stack overflow let's me. Thanks!

Comment: @Tono, the same link was mentioned in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11170036/960757) posted more than year before this one.

Comment: is the C# porting available somewhere?

Comment: The CreateProcessWithTokenW failed for me. I found another approach here that works well https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSCreateLowIntegrityProcess-d7cb5e4d/sourcecode?fileId=52580&pathId=1953311234

Comment: If `CreateProcessWithTokenW` fails, that might be if the "Secondary Logon Service" is disabled. Unfortunately many so-called "optimization" web sites recommend to disable this "unneccessary" service. The [`IShellDispatch2` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43768571/7571258) seems to be more reliable in this regard because it doesn't require this service to be running. A disadvantage is that it gives less control about how the process is created.

Answer (score 16):

C# code for Aaron Margosis [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx):

```
        private static void RunAsDesktopUser(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(fileName));

        // To start process as shell user you will need to carry out these steps:
        // 1. Enable the SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in your current token
        // 2. Get an HWND representing the desktop shell (GetShellWindow)
        // 3. Get the Process ID(PID) of the process associated with that window(GetWindowThreadProcessId)
        // 4. Open that process(OpenProcess)
        // 5. Get the access token from that process (OpenProcessToken)
        // 6. Make a primary token with that token(DuplicateTokenEx)
        // 7. Start the new process with that primary token(CreateProcessWithTokenW)

        var hProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        // Enable SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in this process.  (This won't work if current process is not elevated.)
        try
        {
            var process = GetCurrentProcess();
            if (!OpenProcessToken(process, 0x0020, ref hProcessToken))
                return;

            var tkp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
            {
                PrivilegeCount = 1,
                Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1]
            };

            if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege", ref tkp.Privileges[0].Luid))
                return;

            tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0x00000002;

            if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcessToken, false, ref tkp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                return;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
        }

        // Get an HWND representing the desktop shell.
        // CAVEATS:  This will fail if the shell is not running (crashed or terminated), or the default shell has been
        // replaced with a custom shell.  This also won't return what you probably want if Explorer has been terminated and
        // restarted elevated.
        var hwnd = GetShellWindow();
        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        var hShellProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
        var hShellProcessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        var hPrimaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            // Get the PID of the desktop shell process.
            uint dwPID;
            if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out dwPID) == 0)
                return;

            // Open the desktop shell process in order to query it (get the token)
            hShellProcess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, false, dwPID);
            if (hShellProcess == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            // Get the process token of the desktop shell.
            if (!OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, 0x0002, ref hShellProcessToken))
                return;

            var dwTokenRights = 395U;

            // Duplicate the shell's process token to get a primary token.
            // Based on experimentation, this is the minimal set of rights required for CreateProcessWithTokenW (contrary to current documentation).
            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hShellProcessToken, dwTokenRights, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out hPrimaryToken))
                return;

            // Start the target process with the new token.
            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            if (!CreateProcessWithTokenW(hPrimaryToken, 0, fileName, "", 0, IntPtr.Zero, Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), ref si, out pi))
                return;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(hShellProcessToken);
            CloseHandle(hPrimaryToken);
            CloseHandle(hShellProcess);
        }

    }

    #region Interop

    private struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
        public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    private struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LUID
    {
        public uint LowPart;
        public int HighPart;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
        VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
        VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
        DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
        CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
        SetQuota = 0x00000100,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }

    private enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
    {
        SecurityAnonymous,
        SecurityIdentification,
        SecurityImpersonation,
        SecurityDelegation
    }

    private enum TOKEN_TYPE
    {
        TokenPrimary = 1,
        TokenImpersonation
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref LUID pluid);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint processId);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, uint dwDesiredAccess, IntPtr lpTokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL impersonationLevel, TOKEN_TYPE tokenType, out IntPtr phNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(IntPtr hToken, int dwLogonFlags, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    #endregion
```

Comment: This was a great start, thanks! It's fairly easy to extend it to return a `Process` object and pass arguments: `CreateProcessWithTokenW(hPrimaryToken, 0, fileName, $"\"{fileName}\" {arguments}",...` and `return Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessId);` Note you can wait for the process to exit, but not check its error code.

Comment: how to apply this solution to running my own windows app?

Comment: Hello, i am trying to use this scenario to run the process as elevated user. Example: i am running the code from an admin account (or from SYSTEM account), and need to run a new process as the desktop user (which is not part of the administrators group), but i need to run the new process with admin rights.

Answer (score 11):

This is a really old question that I saw years ago and have revisited now. Since its the first google search result... I'll post my answer here.

All the solutions that I have found are extremely complex and ridiculous. Over the years I have stumbled upon a solution that I have not seen documented anywhere, and haven't really shared until now.

The code is very simple... Essentially we are writing a batch file with the name/path of the executable of the process you want to run, with whatever arguments you want. Then we spawn an explorer.exe process with the path to the batch file...

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test.bat", @"C:\test.exe -randomArgs");

var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "explorer.exe",
        Arguments = @"C:\test.bat",
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "runas",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    }
};
proc.Start();
```

The explorer process that we spawn is immediately killed off by the operating system, However! The root explorer.exe process running runs the batch file! You can give explorer.exe the name of your executable and it will do the same thing, however that method does not support arguments.

For all I know this is a bug or undocumented feature. However I cannot imagine how it could be used maliciously, as it allows de-elevation of permissions... This works in windows 7/8/8.1/10.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of starting the process not as administrator but as a different user?

Comment: @user3700562 because it's using explorer.exe as a gateway to launch the bat file.

Comment: This is not working for me on windows 10. "This app can't run on your pc.". Windows refuses to launch `.CMD` or `.BAT`

Comment: That's a safescreen error. If Safescreen is blocking batch files, that's an entirely different problem. Just tested without safescreen and it still works. One of the apps I maintain also uses this, so it would be a major PIA for me if it fails.

Comment: `.bat` can delete itself after running if you add to it `del %0` line.

Answer (score 6):

Presuming that you are signalling the application to shut down cleanly rather than terminating it, and if you are still able to make changes to the application before releasing your updater, one simple solution would be to have the application launch an interim process before exiting.  You could create the executable for the interim process in a temporary location.  When the update is finished, signal the interim process to relaunch the application and exit.  That way, everything happens naturally and you don't have to mess about.

Another option would be to use [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [`DuplicateToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a copy of the application's security token before killing it.  You can then use [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to relaunch the application in the original context.

Both of these approaches should work even if the updater is running under a different account and/or in a different session to the application.

Answer (score 5):

In my app I originally used [user3122201](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40501607/862099)'s solution, which works very well.  However, I wanted the elevated app to communicate with the low privilege app using anonymous pipes.  To achieve that, I needed a solution that would allow the pipe handles to be inherited.

I came up with the solution below which allows handle inheritance.

Please note another small difference between this solution and user3122201's: the method below runs as the process as the same user, but with restricted access, while user3122201's method runs as process the desktop user.

```
    public static class ProcessHelper
    {
        /// Runs a process as a non-elevated version of the current user.
        public static Process? RunAsRestrictedUser(string fileName, string? args = null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(fileName));

            if (!GetRestrictedSessionUserToken(out var hRestrictedToken))
            {
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                var si = new STARTUPINFO();
                var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
                var cmd = new StringBuilder();
                cmd.Append('"').Append(fileName).Append('"');
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args))
                {
                    cmd.Append(' ').Append(args);
                }

                if (!CreateProcessAsUser(
                    hRestrictedToken,
                    null,
                    cmd,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    true, // inherit handle
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                    ref si,
                    out pi))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessId);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hRestrictedToken);
            }
        }

        // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110126/862099
        private static bool GetRestrictedSessionUserToken(out IntPtr token)
        {
            token = IntPtr.Zero;
            if (!SaferCreateLevel(SaferScope.User, SaferLevel.NormalUser, SaferOpenFlags.Open, out var hLevel, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                return false;
            }

            IntPtr hRestrictedToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = default;
            tml.Label.Sid = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tmlPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                if (!SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(hLevel, IntPtr.Zero, out hRestrictedToken, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // Set the token to medium integrity.
                tml.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY;
                tml.Label.Sid = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!ConvertStringSidToSid("S-1-16-8192", out tml.Label.Sid))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                tmlPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tml));
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(tml, tmlPtr, false);
                if (!SetTokenInformation(hRestrictedToken,
                    TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenIntegrityLevel,
                    tmlPtr, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(tml)))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                token = hRestrictedToken;
                hRestrictedToken = IntPtr.Zero; // make sure finally() doesn't close the handle
            }
            finally
            {
                SaferCloseLevel(hLevel);
                SafeCloseHandle(hRestrictedToken);
                if (tml.Label.Sid != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    LocalFree(tml.Label.Sid);
                }
                if (tmlPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tmlPtr);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public IntPtr Sid;
            public uint Attributes;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL
        {
            public SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Label;
        }

        public enum SaferLevel : uint
        {
            Disallowed = 0,
            Untrusted = 0x1000,
            Constrained = 0x10000,
            NormalUser = 0x20000,
            FullyTrusted = 0x40000
        }

        public enum SaferScope : uint
        {
            Machine = 1,
            User = 2
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SaferOpenFlags : uint
        {
            Open = 1
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool SaferCreateLevel(SaferScope scope, SaferLevel level, SaferOpenFlags openFlags, out IntPtr pLevelHandle, IntPtr lpReserved);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(IntPtr LevelHandle, IntPtr InAccessToken, out IntPtr OutAccessToken, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SaferCloseLevel(IntPtr hLevelHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern bool ConvertStringSidToSid(string StringSid, out IntPtr ptrSid);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        private static bool SafeCloseHandle(IntPtr hObject)
        {
            return (hObject == IntPtr.Zero) ? true : CloseHandle(hObject);
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);

        enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_USER structure that contains the user account of the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenUser = 1,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_GROUPS structure that contains the group accounts associated with the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenGroups,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure that contains the privileges of the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenPrivileges,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_OWNER structure that contains the default owner security identifier (SID) for newly created objects.
            /// </summary>
            TokenOwner,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_PRIMARY_GROUP structure that contains the default primary group SID for newly created objects.
            /// </summary>
            TokenPrimaryGroup,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_DEFAULT_DACL structure that contains the default DACL for newly created objects.
            /// </summary>
            TokenDefaultDacl,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_SOURCE structure that contains the source of the token. TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE access is needed to retrieve this information.
            /// </summary>
            TokenSource,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_TYPE value that indicates whether the token is a primary or impersonation token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenType,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL value that indicates the impersonation level of the token. If the access token is not an impersonation token, the function fails.
            /// </summary>
            TokenImpersonationLevel,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_STATISTICS structure that contains various token statistics.
            /// </summary>
            TokenStatistics,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_GROUPS structure that contains the list of restricting SIDs in a restricted token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenRestrictedSids,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a DWORD value that indicates the Terminal Services session identifier that is associated with the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenSessionId,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_GROUPS_AND_PRIVILEGES structure that contains the user SID, the group accounts, the restricted SIDs, and the authentication ID associated with the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,

            /// <summary>
            /// Reserved.
            /// </summary>
            TokenSessionReference,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a DWORD value that is nonzero if the token includes the SANDBOX_INERT flag.
            /// </summary>
            TokenSandBoxInert,

            /// <summary>
            /// Reserved.
            /// </summary>
            TokenAuditPolicy,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_ORIGIN value.
            /// </summary>
            TokenOrigin,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE value that specifies the elevation level of the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenElevationType,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN structure that contains a handle to another token that is linked to this token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenLinkedToken,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_ELEVATION structure that specifies whether the token is elevated.
            /// </summary>
            TokenElevation,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a DWORD value that is nonzero if the token has ever been filtered.
            /// </summary>
            TokenHasRestrictions,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_ACCESS_INFORMATION structure that specifies security information contained in the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenAccessInformation,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a DWORD value that is nonzero if virtualization is allowed for the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenVirtualizationAllowed,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a DWORD value that is nonzero if virtualization is enabled for the token.
            /// </summary>
            TokenVirtualizationEnabled,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL structure that specifies the token's integrity level.
            /// </summary>
            TokenIntegrityLevel,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a DWORD value that is nonzero if the token has the UIAccess flag set.
            /// </summary>
            TokenUIAccess,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives a TOKEN_MANDATORY_POLICY structure that specifies the token's mandatory integrity policy.
            /// </summary>
            TokenMandatoryPolicy,

            /// <summary>
            /// The buffer receives the token's logon security identifier (SID).
            /// </summary>
            TokenLogonSid,

            /// <summary>
            /// The maximum value for this enumeration
            /// </summary>
            MaxTokenInfoClass
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Boolean SetTokenInformation(
            IntPtr TokenHandle,
            TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass,
            IntPtr TokenInformation,
            UInt32 TokenInformationLength);

        const uint SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY = 0x00000020;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
            IntPtr hToken,
            string? lpApplicationName,
            StringBuilder? lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string? lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a project on codeplex called [User Account Control Helpers](http://uachelpers.codeplex.com/).

The project provides a library for interaction with the UAC mechanism.

In the library you will find a class called `UserAccountControl`. The class
has a static method called `CreateProcessAsStandardUser` to start a
process from an elevated process with standard user rights.

In short, the functions opens the process token of the desktop shell process.
Then, it duplicates that token to get a primary token. This token is then
used to start the new process under the logged on user.

For more information please read the following blog post from [Aaron Margosis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar issue.In the processstartinfo there is a password field,the catch is that you have to supply the password as a secure string.So the code would be like:

```
System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
password.AppendChar('c1');
//append the all characters of your password, you could probably use a loop and then,
Process p =new Process();
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.UserName = Environment.UserName;
p.FileName = file ;
p.Sassword=password;
p.Start();
```

Comment: yes you need the right password. I found this easier compared to the best answer on this forum

Comment: It's not easier if you don't know the password. How can you hope to know the password unless you own the box?

Comment: That is the catch I was talking about @DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 2):

Practical VB.NET code to start a process with default shell permissions from elevated parent process

```
#Region "References"

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

#End Region

Public Class LaunchProcess

#Region "Native Methods"

    <DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function GetShellWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DesiredAccess As Integer, ByRef TokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Private Shared Function OpenProcess(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bInheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal dwProcessId As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function DuplicateTokenEx( _
    ByVal ExistingTokenHandle As IntPtr, _
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As UInt32, _
    ByRef lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
    ByVal ImpersonationLevel As Integer, _
    ByVal TokenType As Integer, _
    ByRef DuplicateTokenHandle As System.IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function LookupPrivilegeValue(lpSystemName As String, lpName As String, ByRef lpLuid As LUID) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function AdjustTokenPrivileges( _
    ByVal TokenHandle As IntPtr, _
    ByVal DisableAllPrivileges As Boolean, _
    ByRef NewState As TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, _
    ByVal BufferLengthInBytes As Integer, _
    ByRef PreviousState As TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, _
    ByRef ReturnLengthInBytes As Integer _
  ) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> Private Shared Function CreateProcessWithTokenW(hToken As IntPtr, dwLogonFlags As Integer, lpApplicationName As String, lpCommandLine As String, dwCreationFlags As Integer, lpEnvironment As IntPtr, lpCurrentDirectory As IntPtr, ByRef lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, ByRef lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Boolean
    End Function

#End Region

#Region "Structures"

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Private Structure SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

        Friend nLength As Integer
        Friend lpSecurityDescriptor As IntPtr
        Friend bInheritHandle As Integer

    End Structure

    Private Structure TOKEN_PRIVILEGES

        Friend PrivilegeCount As Integer
        Friend TheLuid As LUID
        Friend Attributes As Integer

    End Structure

    Private Structure LUID

        Friend LowPart As UInt32
        Friend HighPart As UInt32

    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> Private Structure STARTUPINFO

        Friend cb As Integer
        Friend lpReserved As String
        Friend lpDesktop As String
        Friend lpTitle As String
        Friend dwX As Integer
        Friend dwY As Integer
        Friend dwXSize As Integer
        Friend dwYSize As Integer
        Friend dwXCountChars As Integer
        Friend dwYCountChars As Integer
        Friend dwFillAttribute As Integer
        Friend dwFlags As Integer
        Friend wShowWindow As Short
        Friend cbReserved2 As Short
        Friend lpReserved2 As Integer
        Friend hStdInput As Integer
        Friend hStdOutput As Integer
        Friend hStdError As Integer

    End Structure

    Private Structure PROCESS_INFORMATION

        Friend hProcess As IntPtr
        Friend hThread As IntPtr
        Friend dwProcessId As Integer
        Friend dwThreadId As Integer

    End Structure

#End Region

#Region "Enumerations"

    Private Enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS

        TokenUser = 1
        TokenGroups
        TokenPrivileges
        TokenOwner
        TokenPrimaryGroup
        TokenDefaultDacl
        TokenSource
        TokenType
        TokenImpersonationLevel
        TokenStatistics
        TokenRestrictedSids
        TokenSessionId
        TokenGroupsAndPrivileges
        TokenSessionReference
        TokenSandBoxInert
        TokenAuditPolicy
        TokenOrigin
        TokenElevationType
        TokenLinkedToken
        TokenElevation
        TokenHasRestrictions
        TokenAccessInformation
        TokenVirtualizationAllowed
        TokenVirtualizationEnabled
        TokenIntegrityLevel
        TokenUIAccess
        TokenMandatoryPolicy
        TokenLogonSid
        MaxTokenInfoClass

    End Enum

#End Region

#Region "Constants"

    Private Const SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = &H2L
    Private Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
    Private Const TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = &H1
    Private Const TOKEN_DUPLICATE = &H2
    Private Const TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = &H4
    Private Const TOKEN_QUERY = &H8
    Private Const TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = &H10
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = &H20
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = &H40
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = &H80
    Private Const TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = &H100
    Private Const SecurityImpersonation = 2
    Private Const TokenPrimary = 1
    Private Const SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME = "SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege"

#End Region

#Region "Methods"

    Friend Shared Sub LaunchFile(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal IsWaitToFinish As Boolean)

        Try

            'Enable the SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege in current token
            Dim HPrcsToken As IntPtr = Nothing
            OpenProcessToken(Process.GetCurrentProcess.Handle, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, HPrcsToken)

            Dim TokenPrvlgs As TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
            TokenPrvlgs.PrivilegeCount = 1
            LookupPrivilegeValue(Nothing, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, TokenPrvlgs.TheLuid)
            TokenPrvlgs.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED

            AdjustTokenPrivileges(HPrcsToken, False, TokenPrvlgs, 0, Nothing, Nothing)

            'Get window handle representing the desktop shell
            Dim HShellWnd As IntPtr = GetShellWindow()

            'Get the ID of the desktop shell process
            Dim ShellPID As IntPtr
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(HShellWnd, ShellPID)

            'Open the desktop shell process in order to get the process token
            Dim HShellPrcs As IntPtr = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, ShellPID)
            Dim HShellPrcSToken As IntPtr = Nothing
            Dim HPrimaryToken As IntPtr = Nothing

            'Get the process token of the desktop shell
            OpenProcessToken(HShellPrcs, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, HShellPrcSToken)

            'Duplicate the shell's process token to get a primary token
            Dim TokenRights As UInteger = TOKEN_QUERY Or TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY Or TOKEN_DUPLICATE Or TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT Or TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID
            DuplicateTokenEx(HShellPrcSToken, TokenRights, Nothing, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, HPrimaryToken)

            Dim StartInfo As STARTUPINFO = Nothing
            Dim PrcsInfo As PROCESS_INFORMATION = Nothing

            StartInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(StartInfo)
            Dim IsSuccessed As Boolean = CreateProcessWithTokenW(HPrimaryToken, 1, FilePath, "", 0, Nothing, Nothing, StartInfo, PrcsInfo)

            If IsSuccessed = True Then

                If IsWaitToFinish = True Then

                    Try

                        Dim Prcs As Process = Process.GetProcessById(PrcsInfo.dwProcessId)
                        Prcs.WaitForExit()

                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                End If

            Else

                'Could not launch process with shell token may be the process needs admin rights to launch, we will try to launch it with default parent process permissions.

                Dim Prcs As New Process
                Prcs.StartInfo.FileName = FilePath
                Prcs.Start()

                If IsWaitToFinish = True Then Prcs.WaitForExit()

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

LaunchProcess class usage

```
LaunchProcess.LaunchFile("C:\Program Files\Test\text.exe", False)
```

You may use Telerik code converter to convert code to C# http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CreateProcessWithLogonW function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or similar [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CreateProcessWithTokenW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As the writer describe this problem doesn't solved .
I have the same problem now I wanna describe how I solved this.

As you know it is not that easy but the best solution is that you force computer to start the "*.exe" file by another non-admin process . What I do was creating a task on Task Scheduler `without Highest Privilege` Parameters, It means making a time or run this task manually.

It seems stupid but it seems there is no way.

You can see [this link](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) that describe how to create a new Task on windows task scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Raymond Chen's proposed solution](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) of using COM to let Explorer do the hard work for you.