# Removing Administrator Privilages from Process

Tags: winapi, uac, access-token, elevated-privileges, privilege-elevation

With the help of this great [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff420334.aspx), my first idea was to simply check if the process is using an elevated Administrator group, and using `AdjustTokenGroups()` I would set the Administrator group to `SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY`. Unfortunately though, we can't modify the administrator group on the currently running process as it also has the `SE_GROUP_MANDATORY` attribute, which makes it inelligable for changing.

The MSDN document has this to say about it:

The `AdjustTokenGroups` function cannot disable groups with the `SE_GROUP_MANDATORY` attribute in the `TOKEN_GROUPS` structure. Use `CreateRestrictedToken` instead.

So, I am done the following code to achieve this;

```
bool _IsNewProcessLaunched()
{
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;   
    bool hasRestarted = false;

    if (!OpenProcessToken( GetCurrentProcess(), 
        TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS, 
        &hToken )) 
    {
        return hasRestarted;
    }

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSID = NULL;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuth = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

    if(! AllocateAndInitializeSid( &SIDAuth, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
        DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        &pSID) ) 
    {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        hToken = NULL;
        return hasRestarted;
    }

    BOOL isAdmin = FALSE;
    BOOL ok = CheckTokenMembership(NULL, pSID, &isAdmin);

    // Create the SID structure for the administrator SID
    SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES adminSID = {0};
    adminSID.Sid = pSID;

    // Create a restricted token which denies the administrator group
    HANDLE restrictedToken;

    CreateRestrictedToken(hToken,RESTR,DISABLE_MAX_PRIVILEGE,&adminSID,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,&restrictedToken);

    //Create startup info
    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";
    si.cb = sizeof( si );

    // Get the current executables name
    TCHAR exePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL,exePath,MAX_PATH);

    // Start the new (non-administrator elevated) restricted process
    if( CreateProcessAsUser(restrictedToken,exePath,NULL,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi) == 0)
        hasRestarted = false;
    else
        hasRestarted  = true;

    return hasRestarted;
}
```

But new process is still running as **administrator** rather than as the **normal user**.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: You have a very sloppy programming style. RESTR is never defined, and the parameters for CreateRestrictedToken() are completely out of order. If you pass SidsToDisable, you must set DisableSidCount = 1. Any errors returned from the API are completely ignored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are restricting the calling process's token, the launched process will be run with the same **user account** as the calling process, just with restricted permissions.  Remember, under UAC, administrators do not have full admin rights without elevation.  `CreateRestrictedToken()` creates a token with restricted permissions.  So even though the user may be **administrator** does not mean the launched process will run with administrative rights.

BTW, there is a simplier API, known as the [Safer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721849.aspx#safer_functions), that you can use instead of `CreateRestrictedToken()`:

```
#include <WinSafer.h>

bool _IsNewProcessLaunched()
{
    // Create the restricted token.

    SAFER_LEVEL_HANDLE hLevel = NULL;
    if (!SaferCreateLevel(SAFER_SCOPEID_USER, SAFER_LEVELID_NORMALUSER, SAFER_LEVEL_OPEN, &hLevel, NULL))
    {
        return false;
    }

    HANDLE hRestrictedToken = NULL;
    if (!SaferComputeTokenFromLevel(hLevel, NULL, &hRestrictedToken, 0, NULL))
    {
        SaferCloseLevel(hLevel);
        return false;
    }

    SaferCloseLevel(hLevel);

    // Set the token to medium integrity.

    TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = {0};
    tml.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY; 
    // alternatively, use CreateWellKnownSid(WinMediumLabelSid) instead...
    if (!ConvertStringSidToSid(TEXT("S-1-16-8192"), &(tml.Label.Sid)))
    {
        CloseHandle(hRestrictedToken);
        return false;
    }

    if (!SetTokenInformation(hRestrictedToken, TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, sizeof(tml) + GetLengthSid(tml.Label.Sid))))
    {
        LocalFree(tml.Label.Sid);
        CloseHandle(hRestrictedToken);
        return false;
    }

    LocalFree(tml.Label.Sid);

    // Create startup info

    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    si.cb = sizeof( si );
    si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

    // Get the current executable's name
    TCHAR exePath[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, exePath, MAX_PATH);

    // Start the new (non-elevated) restricted process
    if (!CreateProcessAsUser(hRestrictedToken, exePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(hRestrictedToken);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hRestrictedToken);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Interesting API that I have never seen before! Please note that your code creates a token which has the Admin group removed, but the new process starts with Integrity Level = High if the calling process also runs High. So this is definitely a big bug in your code. After creating the Token you must call SetTokenInformation() with TokenIntegrityLevel and SDDL_ML_MEDIUM.

Comment: Apart from that there is a BIG FAT BUG in Windows 10: When you create a process with the above code and set Integrity Level = Medium the new process will be elevated!! GetTokenInformation(TokenElevation)  On Windows 7 this does not happen.