# How to start a non-administrator process from an administrator powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, administrator

From an Administrator PowerShell, is there a way to spawn another shell (or .exe) under a different (for instance, non-administrator) user? I know this is possible in Linux/Bash via su {username}, but does Windows allow it?

This question has been answered for [C++ here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948064/how-to-launch-non-elevated-administrator-process-from-elevated-administrator-con) and for [C# here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169431/how-to-start-a-new-process-without-administrator-privileges-from-a-process-with), but I would like to know if it is possible in PowerShell.

Comment: Not sure if you meant by this or not: `runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell.exe -command 'hostname'`

Comment: Yes, slap a final quote mark on that and then convert it to an answer. I'm also curious what the different trustlevels are, but it looks like 0x40000 is some sort of admin.

Comment: Note that this [doesn't completely remove elevated privileges from the child.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30970434/886887)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863475/starting-non-elevated-prompt-from-elevated-session/40868875#40868875

Comment: Thanks, @iRon. Would be duplicate except it doesn't have accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "powershell.exe -command 'hostname'"
```