# Clientname is not set after a process is created with CreateProcessAsUser and CreateEnvironmentBlock

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services, environment-variables

I have written a C# service running under the local system account. I use it to spawn a process when a user logs in on a Terminalserver. The service implements the `OnSessionChange` method and receives `SessionChangeDescription` messages with the corresponding SessionID.

I use this SessionID to get an access token from the user with `WTSQueryUserToken`. I convert this token into a primary token and pass it to `CreateEnvironmentBlock` to retrieve a pointer to the users environment variables. After some further preparations I call the `CreateProcessAsUser`function to finally spawn my process as the recently logged on user on his `winsta0\default` desktop.

When I investigate the process with `ProcessExplorer` I see that there is no CLIENTNAME environment variable in the process context. Yet the applications needs this variable.

I wonder what I've done wrong. Or maybe I am missing something. The user profile should be loaded, since I react when the user has logged in.

Is it possible, that there is some timing issue? Or does the CLIENTNAME var gets applied to a process in any other way?

Here is how I call the `CreateEnvironmentBlock` function:

```
    private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentFromToken(IntPtr token)
    {
        // Get a pointer to the environment variables from the specified user access token
        IntPtr newEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (!WinApi.CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref newEnvironment, token, false))
        {
            newEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        return newEnvironment;
    }
```

If you need any more information or code samples, feel free to ask.

Comment: you call `CreateEnvironmentBlock` - so in what problem look - are `CLIENTNAME` string exist in `newEnvironment` ? and `I convert this token into a primary token ` - the `WTSQueryUserToken` obtains the primary access token  - so nothing need to convert

Comment: @RbMm I will write some code that goes through the `newEnvironment` array. Does it do some harm if I use `DuplicateTokenEx` to convert a primary token into a primary token?

Comment: no, will be no harm if you call `DuplicateTokenEx`m but for what you need duplicate it ? you can just use it as is returned from `WTSQueryUserToken`. you need look `PWSTR sz = (PWSTR)lpEnvironment;
   while (*sz)
   {
    DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);
    sz += wcslen(sz) + 1;
   }` are `CLIENTNAME` present. if it not present in block - it will be not present and in child process. if it present - may be you not use `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` flag in `CreateProcessAsUser`

Comment: You may have to call [`LoadUserProfile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281(v=vs.85).aspx) before calling `CreateEnvironmentBlock()`.

Comment: @RbMm I do use the `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` flag (value is 0x00000400) in the creationFlags for `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Comment: @zett42 Is this really needed? Is the service "faster" than the actual login process of the user? (Since I am reacting on the `WTS_SESSION_LOGON` message)

Comment: I'm not really sure, you could just try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the environment variables depend not only from user *SID* but from *SessionId* too, because some variable was per session.

we can view in registry under `HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Volatile Environment` user environment variables. and `SessionId` sub keys here exist. under sub key - per session variable
[image]

so `CreateEnvironmentBlock` must do next - get user *SID* from token, open `HKEY_USERS\<SID>\Volatile Environment` key, and query it values.

then must query `SessionId` **from token** via `GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenSessionId, )` and query `Volatile Environment\SessionId` sub key.

but by mistake system use `SessionId` from current process *PEB* instead from get it token. the next code is in system dll:

```
WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
StringCchPrintfW(buf, RTL_NUMBER_OF(buf), 
    L"%s\\%d", L"Volatile Environment", RtlGetCurrentPeb()->SessionId);
```

[image]

*mov rax,gs:[60h]// rax -> PEB

2c0h this is offset of SessionId in PEB*

when you exec application from service - the `SessionId` in `PEB` was 0, as result `CLIENTNAME` and `SESSIONNAME` not added to environment block.

this is common system bug. for test you can run two `cmd.exe` - one not elevated (exec from *explorer.exe*) and one run as admin ( exec from *svchost.exe -k netsvcs*) and then run in both `set` command - it show environment strings. you can note that in not elevated `cmd.exe` exist string `SESSIONNAME=Console` (or `SESSIONNAME=RDP-Tcp#N` if you run it from rdp) and , if you in rdp, `CLIENTNAME=DESKTOP-xxx`. but in elevated (run as admin) *cmd.exe* - no this strings. this is because `CreateEnvironmentBlock` called from *svchost.exe -k netsvcs* which have `SessionId` == 0

for fix this can be 2 way:

easy, but not correct:

```
        _PEB* peb = RtlGetCurrentPeb();
        DWORD _SessionId = peb->SessionId, SessionId, rcb;

        if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenSessionId, &SessionId, sizeof(SessionId), &rcb))
        {
            peb->SessionId = SessionId;
        }

        PVOID Environment;
        BOOL fOk = CreateEnvironmentBlock(&Environment, hToken, FALSE);

        peb->SessionId = _SessionId;
```

idea here - temporary replace `SessionId` in *PEB* to `SessionId` from token. this will be work. bu bad here - what if another thread in concurrent will use `SessionId` in *PEB* ?

another way, relative big code, but correct - yourself walk through `SessionId` sub key and extend environment block.

```
void AddSessionEnv(HANDLE hToken, PVOID Environment, PVOID* pNewEnvironment)
{
    SIZE_T cb = 1, len;
    PWSTR sz = (PWSTR)Environment;
    while (*sz)
    {
        len = wcslen(sz) + 1;
        sz += len;
        cb += len;
    }

    DWORD SessionId, rcb;
    if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenSessionId, &SessionId, sizeof(SessionId), &rcb))
    {
        PROFILEINFO pi = { sizeof(pi), PI_NOUI, L"*" };
        if (LoadUserProfileW(hToken, &pi))
        {
            WCHAR SubKey[48];
            swprintf(SubKey, L"Volatile Environment\\%d", SessionId);
            HKEY hKey;

            if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyExW((HKEY)pi.hProfile, SubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey))
            {
                cb *= sizeof(WCHAR);

                ULONG cbNeed = 0x200, cbAllocated;
                PVOID NewEnvironment;
                do 
                {
                    if (NewEnvironment = LocalAlloc(0, cb + (cbAllocated = cbNeed)))
                    {
                        cbNeed = AddSessionEnv(hKey, (PWSTR)NewEnvironment, cbAllocated);

                        if (cbNeed && cbAllocated >= cbNeed)
                        {
                            memcpy((PBYTE)NewEnvironment + cbNeed, Environment, cb);
                            *pNewEnvironment = NewEnvironment;
                            break;
                        }

                        LocalFree(NewEnvironment);
                    }

                } while (cbNeed);

                RegCloseKey(hKey);
            }
            UnloadUserProfile(hToken, pi.hProfile);
        }
    }
}

static volatile UCHAR guz;

ULONG AddSessionEnv(HANDLE hKey, PWSTR sz, ULONG Length)
{
    LONG status;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    ULONG TotalLength = 0, DataLength, Index = 0, cb = 0, rcb = sizeof(KEY_VALUE_FULL_INFORMATION) + 256;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PKEY_VALUE_FULL_INFORMATION pkvfi;
    };

    do 
    {
        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb) cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);

            if (0 <= (status = ZwEnumerateValueKey(hKey, Index, KeyValueFullInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)) && 
                pkvfi->Type == REG_SZ &&
                (DataLength = pkvfi->DataLength) &&
                !(DataLength & (sizeof(WCHAR) - 1)))
            {
                static const UNICODE_STRING CharSet = { 2 * sizeof(WCHAR), 2 * sizeof(WCHAR), L"="};

                USHORT NonInclusivePrefixLength;
                UNICODE_STRING Name = { (USHORT)pkvfi->NameLength, Name.Length, pkvfi->Name };

                // not add strings which containing 0 or `=` symbol or emply
                if (Name.Length && RtlFindCharInUnicodeString(0, &Name, &CharSet, &NonInclusivePrefixLength) == STATUS_NOT_FOUND)
                {
                    UNICODE_STRING Value = { 
                        (USHORT)DataLength, 
                        Value.Length, 
                        (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(pkvfi, pkvfi->DataOffset) 
                    };

                    PWSTR szEnd = (PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(Value.Buffer, DataLength - sizeof(WCHAR));

                    if (!*szEnd) Value.Length -= sizeof(WCHAR);

                    // not add empty strings or containing 0 or `=` symbol
                    if (Value.Length && RtlFindCharInUnicodeString(0, &Value, &CharSet, &NonInclusivePrefixLength) == STATUS_NOT_FOUND)
                    {
                        ULONG cbNeed = Name.Length + 2 * sizeof(WCHAR) + Value.Length;

                        if (Length >= cbNeed)
                        {
                            sz += 1 + swprintf(sz, L"%wZ=%wZ", &Name, &Value), Length -= cbNeed;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Length = 0;
                        }

                        TotalLength += cbNeed;
                    }
                }
            }

        } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW || status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL );

        Index++;

    } while (status != STATUS_NO_MORE_ENTRIES);

    return TotalLength;
}
```

and use this code as:

```
        PVOID Environment, NewEnvironment = 0;

        if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&Environment, hToken, FALSE))
        {
            AddSessionEnv(hToken, Environment, &NewEnvironment);

            CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, *, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, 
                NewEnvironment ? NewEnvironment : Environment, *);

            if (NewEnvironment)
            {
                LocalFree(NewEnvironment);
            }
            DestroyEnvironmentBlock(Environment);
        }
```

the definition of `RtlFindCharInUnicodeString` which i use, for for comfort

```
enum {
    RTL_FIND_CHAR_IN_UNICODE_STRING_START_AT_END = 1,
    RTL_FIND_CHAR_IN_UNICODE_STRING_COMPLEMENT_CHAR_SET = 2,
    RTL_FIND_CHAR_IN_UNICODE_STRING_CASE_INSENSITIVE = 4
};

NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
RtlFindCharInUnicodeString(
                                 ULONG Flags,
                                 PCUNICODE_STRING StringToSearch,
                                 PCUNICODE_STRING CharSet,
                                 USHORT *NonInclusivePrefixLength
                                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, it appears that `CreateEnvironmentBlock` only sets `CLIENTNAME` if the process is running in the same Remote Desktop session that is associated with the token.  Impersonation did not make any difference.  This is arguably a bug in Windows.

To work around this, you could add `CLIENTNAME` to the environment block yourself, or you could launch a process in the user's session to call `CreateEnvironmentBlock` function on your behalf.

Comment: yes, you almost correct - `CreateEnvironmentBlock` use the caller process `SessionId` for check environment variables, but not `SessionId` from token. but some env vars depend from `SessionId` - look at `HKEY_USERS\S-*\Volatile Environment\SessionId` - here usually `CLIENTNAME` and `SESSIONNAME`. how i found if run some process normal - exist string `SESSIONNAME=Console` in it env. but if run it as admin - no this string, because process is exec from `svchost.exe` in this case, which run in session 0

Comment: @RbMm, when I ran my test code in a mismatched session (neither session zero nor the session associated with the token) it didn't set `CLIENTNAME` at all.  I thought it might retrieve the client name associated with the session the code was running in, but it didn't.  I suppose that's because the target user account wouldn't have a corresponding entry for the session inside `Volatile Environment`.

Comment: i test the with `SESSIONNAME` string, note that it exist in all not elevated processes. but if i run process as adim - no this var. can easy test this in own code - run test program, which query this string elevated and not elevated. this because `CreateEnvironmentBlock` use `SessionId` from *PEB* but not from given token. about `CLIENTNAME`, how it set in remote desktop - need check. but in all case it readed from registry node

Comment: yes, with `CLIENTNAME` absolute the same situation, simply need enter to windows via rdp. simplest way for check - run 2 `cmd.exe` (as admin and not elevated) and run `set` cmd. you can view that in not elevated `cmd.exe` - `CLIENTNAME=DESKTOP-2N5ODLB` and `SESSIONNAME=RDP-Tcp#3` when in run as admin cmd.exe - no this strings.

Comment: @wolf633 `it appears that CreateEnvironmentBlock only sets CLIENTNAME if the process is running in the same Remote Desktop session that is associated with the token` - this is 100% exactly. I, in own answer, simply explain why this - because *CreateEnvironmentBlock* use *SessionId* from calling process *PEB* but not from token. and only when it the same (process session id == token session id) the correct `CLIENTNAME` is assigned. you can first try short code. despite theoretically it not 100% correct, in practice possibility of some side effect is very low

Comment: Interesting. I am going to use @RbMm 's code and translate it into C#. I think "injecting" the `CLIENTNAME` into the process environment is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: @wolf633 - so you need direct append string `CLIENTNAME=***` to `newEnvironment` returned by *CreateEnvironmentBlock*. I in my code do the same, only not hardcode this single string but walk registry key and add all values. but you can query this single value or get `CLIENTNAME` in some another way

Comment: The only problem with RbMm's code is that it depends on the structure of the Volatile Environment key, which is undocumented (AFAIK) and hence *theoretically* subject to change.  In practice, this is unlikely to be an issue, so if you're comfortable with it I'm not going to argue. :-)