# How do start a process as a normal user?

Tags: c++, windows

There is a launcher - a program in C++, which you need to run as administrator. The launcher launches another process as well on behalf of the administrator and because of this, third-party programs (AutoHotkey) running with the rights of a normal user can not access it. The second process does not require administrator rights, so I would like to implement the launch with the rights of a normal user. How to do it?

At the moment I'm running the process using `boost::process::system`.

Comment: you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921237/6401656)

Comment: I know of two relatively simple ways that rely on the normal case in which the Windows shell is Explorer running non-elevated. The first way gives you more control and preserves your process as the parent: duplicate Explorer's access token (`GetShellWindow`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, `OpenProcess`, `OpenProcessToken`, `DuplicateTokenEx`) and call `CreateProcessWithTokenW`. The [2nd way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) is simpler: get the `Shell.Application` object in Explorer and call `ShellExecute` via its `IShell­Dispatch2` interface.

Comment: @eryksun - instead explorer (which can not exist or exist multiple) we need any process token with `AuthenticationId` (logon session) the same as in our linked token. so can enumerate processes and search for such token luid, but not by name. however I prefer first got tcb privilege, which is possible from elevated process and duplicate self linked token as primary

Comment: @RbMm, SeTcbPrivilege (act as part of the OS) is not granted to an elevated administrator, not by default at least. That's available when running as SYSTEM, typically from a service, so it's unrelated to this question. I'm aware we can search for the logon authentication ID of the elevated user's linked token, but if `GetShellWindow` succeeds, it's a more efficient, direct approach to use the shell's token. Also, if it's an OTS logon, the linked token may not actually be in use by any other process.

Comment: @eryksun - but we can open system process token which have `SeTcbPrivilege` and impersonate with it - this is perfect work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raymond Chen has a blog article on this very topic:

[How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643)

> Going from an unelevated process to an elevated process is easy. You can run a process with elevation by passing the `runas` verb to Shell­Execute or ShellExecute­Ex.
>
> **Going the other way is trickier**. For one thing, it's really hard to munge your token to remove the elevation nature properly. And for another thing, even if you could do it, it's not the right thing to do, because the unelevated user may be different from the elevated user.
>
> ...
>
> **The solution here is to go back to Explorer and ask Explorer to launch the program for you**. Since Explorer is running as the original unelevated user, the program ... will run as [the user].

His article provides the following code to launch an unelevated process, and a detailed explanation of what the code is actually doing (the `FindDesktopFolderView` function mentioned below is defined in his [Manipulating the positions of desktop icons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130318-00/?p=4933) blog article):

```
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include <shldisp.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// FindDesktopFolderView incorporated by reference

void GetDesktopAutomationObject(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    CComPtr<IShellView> spsv;
    FindDesktopFolderView(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spsv));
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spdispView;
    spsv->GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, IID_PPV_ARGS(&spdispView));
    spdispView->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
}

void ShellExecuteFromExplorer(
    PCWSTR pszFile,
    PCWSTR pszParameters = nullptr,
    PCWSTR pszDirectory = nullptr,
    PCWSTR pszOperation = nullptr,
    int nShowCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL)
{
    CComPtr<IShellFolderViewDual> spFolderView;
    GetDesktopAutomationObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spFolderView));
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spdispShell;
    spFolderView->get_Application(&spdispShell);
    CComQIPtr<IShellDispatch2>(spdispShell)
        ->ShellExecute(CComBSTR(pszFile),
                        CComVariant(pszParameters ? pszParameters : L""),
                        CComVariant(pszDirectory ? pszDirectory : L""),
                        CComVariant(pszOperation ? pszOperation : L""),
                        CComVariant(nShowCmd));
}

int __cdecl wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) return 0;

    CCoInitialize init;
    ShellExecuteFromExplorer(
        argv[1],
        argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : L"",
        argc >= 4 ? argv[3] : L"",
        argc >= 5 ? argv[4] : L"",
        argc >= 6 ? _wtoi(argv[5]) : SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if we run as admin (more concrete have *S-1-5-32-544 'Administrators'* group enabled in token) we can open local system process token (it grant all needed to as access for 'Administrators'). 
so we can do next:

- get self terminal session id
- enable debug privileges in token, for be able open any process with
  `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`
- enumerate running processes in system
- open process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`
- open process token with `TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE`
- query token privileges - are it have
  `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE` and `SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE` -
  it need for call [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) and `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` it
  require for [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx)
- if token have all this privileges (LocalSystem token have) -
  duplicate this token to `TokenImpersonation` type.
- if need enable some of this 3 privileges in token
- impersonate with this token

and now we can

- call `WTSQueryUserToken` with self session id - for get not elevated
  user token
- and finally `CreateProcessAsUser` with this token
- reset impersonation

code:

```
static volatile UCHAR guz;

ULONG RunNonElevated(_In_ ULONG SessionId,
                     _In_ HANDLE hToken, 
                     _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpApplicationName,
                     _Inout_opt_ LPWSTR lpCommandLine,
                     _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
                     _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
                     _In_ BOOL bInheritHandles,
                     _In_ DWORD dwCreationFlags,
                     _In_opt_ LPVOID lpEnvironment,
                     _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
                     _In_ LPSTARTUPINFOW lpStartupInfo,
                     _Out_ LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation)
{
    ULONG err;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, Privileges[SE_MAX_WELL_KNOWN_PRIVILEGE]);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        ::PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptp;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenPrivileges, buf, cb, &rcb))
        {
            if (ULONG PrivilegeCount = ptp->PrivilegeCount)
            {
                int n = 3;
                BOOL fAdjust = FALSE;

                ::PLUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges = ptp->Privileges;
                do 
                {
                    switch (Privileges->Luid.LowPart)
                    {
                    case SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE:
                    case SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE:
                    case SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE:
                        if (!(Privileges->Attributes & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED))
                        {
                            Privileges->Attributes |= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
                            fAdjust = TRUE;
                        }

                        if (!--n)
                        {
                            err = NOERROR;

                            if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, 
                                TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, 
                                0, ::SecurityImpersonation, ::TokenImpersonation, 
                                &hToken))
                            {
                                if (fAdjust)
                                {
                                    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, ptp, rcb, NULL, NULL);
                                    err = GetLastError();
                                }

                                if (err == NOERROR)
                                {
                                    if (SetThreadToken(0, hToken))
                                    {
                                        HANDLE hUserToken;
                                        if (WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId, &hUserToken))
                                        {
                                            if (!CreateProcessAsUserW(hUserToken, 
                                                lpApplicationName,
                                                lpCommandLine,
                                                lpProcessAttributes,
                                                lpThreadAttributes,
                                                bInheritHandles,
                                                dwCreationFlags,
                                                lpEnvironment,
                                                lpCurrentDirectory,
                                                lpStartupInfo,
                                                lpProcessInformation))
                                            {
                                                err = GetLastError();
                                            }

                                            CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            err = GetLastError();
                                        }
                                        SetThreadToken(0, 0);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        err = GetLastError();
                                    }
                                }

                                CloseHandle(hToken);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                err = GetLastError();
                            }

                            return err;
                        }
                    }
                } while (Privileges++, --PrivilegeCount);
            }

            return ERROR_NOT_FOUND;
        }

    } while ((err = GetLastError()) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

    return err;
}

ULONG RunNonElevated(_In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpApplicationName,
                     _Inout_opt_ LPWSTR lpCommandLine,
                     _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
                     _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
                     _In_ BOOL bInheritHandles,
                     _In_ DWORD dwCreationFlags,
                     _In_opt_ LPVOID lpEnvironment,
                     _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpCurrentDirectory,
                     _In_ LPSTARTUPINFOW lpStartupInfo,
                     _Out_ LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation
                     )
{

    ULONG SessionId;
    if (!ProcessIdToSessionId(GetCurrentProcessId(), &SessionId))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    BOOLEAN b;
    RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, b);

    ULONG err = NOERROR;

    // much more effective of course use NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation) here
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0), hToken;

    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32W pe = { sizeof(pe) };

        if (Process32FirstW(hSnapshot, &pe))
        {
            err = ERROR_NOT_FOUND;

            do 
            {
                if (pe.th32ProcessID && pe.th32ParentProcessID)
                {
                    if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe.th32ProcessID))
                    {
                        if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken))
                        {
                            err = RunNonElevated(
                                SessionId,
                                hToken, 
                                lpApplicationName,
                                lpCommandLine,
                                lpProcessAttributes,
                                lpThreadAttributes,
                                bInheritHandles,
                                dwCreationFlags,
                                lpEnvironment,
                                lpCurrentDirectory,
                                lpStartupInfo,
                                lpProcessInformation);

                            CloseHandle(hToken);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            err = GetLastError();
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        err = GetLastError();
                    }
                }
            } while (err && Process32NextW(hSnapshot, &pe));
        }
        else
        {
            err = GetLastError();
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }

    return err;
}
```

and test:

```
void test()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si)};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    WCHAR ApplicationName[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ComSpec", ApplicationName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(ApplicationName)))
    {
        if (!RunNonElevated(ApplicationName, L"cmd /k whoami.exe /priv /groups",0,0,0,0,0,0,&si, &pi))
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        }
    }
}
```

with this we can not only run not elevated process, but ,if need, start it with duplicated handles

Comment: @RemyLebeau - it impersonating not by random token (process as you said), but by token which have required for as privileges - `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE`, `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE`. and i use not token of *elevated user* - i use **linked** token, which is not elevated. my code ,despite more big, better and more universal and power, compare Raymond's

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *Raymond's approach launches the new process using the user who is logged in to the current session, not the elevated user.* - exactly this and i do. - you can view that i use `tlt.LinkedToken` for create process. it exactly corresponded to not elevated user logon session

Comment: however my code not depend are explorer run at all in system

Comment: impersonate of "rundom" token we need for 1.) get primary form linked token (for this calling thread must have `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE`, however this not documented) and 2.) for call `CreateProcessAsUserW` (`SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` and `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE` need - documented). token i use correct - linked from elevated process, if it exist, otherwise we need direct call `CreateProcess`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i need concrete privilege in token - `SE_TCB_PRIVILEGE` and `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE` - **any** token with this privileges is ok. i use it for get linked token and `CreateProcessAsUser` - so any *random* is ok here. and i use linked token (so from logon session from which was elevation). *which may be a different user than the one logged into the current session* - no, you mistake here. my code is absolutely accurate and correct

Comment: @RemyLebeau - again - the **linked** process token - this is token from logon session, which exec our process with elevation. this is most correct choise use exactly this token. my code is absolute correct and perfect worked on all systems

Comment: You'll probably need to fall back on using the shell token (e.g. starting with `GetShellWindow`) if the elevated user is logged on with an over-the-shoulder UAC consent (i.e. the session user is a standard user, and the elevated administrator is not the session user). In this case the elevation type is `TokenElevationTypeFull`, but there is no linked token; the limited-token and its logon session is already deleted, and trying to get the linked token fails with `ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION`.

Comment: @eryksun - in this case (non admin user) elevation type will be `TokenElevationTypeDefault` (not `TokenElevationTypeFull`), but really with `TokenElevationTypeDefault`  no linked token (session), so will be not worked in this case

Comment: No, I just checked this, the elevation type is full, not default.

Comment: @eryksun - strange, i also check this (run from guest elevated program) - the token is exactly `TokenElevationTypeDefault`

Comment: @eryksun - yes, i recheck - you are right - i elevate to built-in admin. in this case i got `TokenElevationTypeDefault`. if elevate to another admin user - really got `TokenElevationTypeFull` and `STATUS_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION` error

Comment: Actually, since you have SeTcbPrivilege via impersonation, just get the session ID and call `WTSQueryUserToken`.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, just think about this :)