# P/Invoke method with low integrity

Tags: c#, security, pinvoke

I am trying to P/invoke some method from my C# code.

The main process is running in user/system context, but I have some unsafe external code running (using P/Invoke) which might be insecure.

Is there a way to run those method in low integrity mode?

Comment: You need to run that code in a different process

Answer (score 1):

Run that code in a different process. You can't use `Process.Start()`, since that will take the privileges of the current process.

A suggestion is done in this post how to circumvent the `Process.Start()` issue: [How to start a new process without administrator privileges from a process with administrator privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169431/993547)

Comment: The process is running user context, but I want the methods run in even lower privileges - low integrity mode - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx so I don't think your topic edit is also correct