# Is there is a way that program is not asking for Admin password?

Tags: c#

When I am trying to start "cmd.exe" as a Administrator, it won't ask for password and I can execute commands.

Below code is working good, but it is asking Admin password.

Is there a way that it should resolve automatically and run under local admin account?

```
string subCommand = @"dir";
        string subCommandArgs = @"c:\";
        string subCommandFinal = @"cmd /K \""" + subCommand.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + " " + subCommandArgs.Replace(@"\", @"\\") + @"\""";
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("runas.exe");
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        string finalArgs = @"/env /user:Administrator """ + subCommandFinal + @"""";
        procStartInfo.Arguments = finalArgs;
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169431/how-to-start-a-new-process-without-administrator-privileges-from-a-process-with

Comment: You only need to set the verb to **runas**. See the dupe link from me

Comment: @SirRufo, settings verbs to runas not working

Comment: @user584018 the **runas** verb is doing the same as when you start an exe from explorer with **Run As Administrator**.

Comment: Yes, @SirRufo, Thanks! It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when starting the program you can test if the program runs as administrator and if not restart it as administrator, whereby the user is asked for pressing ok only once.

```
    void RestartIfNeeded() {
        if (!IsAdmin() {
            Process p= new Process {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                    FileName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName,
                    Arguments = //parameters here,
                    //Following two lines make process start as admin
                    Verb = "runas";
                    UseShellExecute = true;
                }
            }
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            p.Dispose();
            Enviroment.Exit(p.ExitCode)
        }
    }
    bool IsAdmin() {
            try {
                return new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()) 
                    .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If your process should start at startup you can use the "Run with highest privileges" function of the windows task scheduler.

```
                public static bool InitalizeScheduledTask() {
string TaskName=//TaskName here;
                    XNamespace taskNamespace =
                        XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task");
                    XElement taskContents = new XElement(taskNamespace + "Task", new XAttribute("version", "1.4"),
                        new XElement(taskNamespace + "RegistrationInfo",
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Date", DateTimeToWin32Format(DateTime.Now)),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Author", WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Description",
                                "[Description here] "),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "URI", $"\\{TaskName}")),
                        new XElement(taskNamespace + "Triggers",
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "LogonTrigger", new XElement(taskNamespace + "Enabled", true))),
                        new XElement(taskNamespace + "Principals",
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Principal", new XAttribute("id", "Author"),
                                new XElement(taskNamespace + "GroupId", "S-1-5-32-545"),
                                new XElement(taskNamespace + "RunLevel", "HighestAvailable"))),
                        new XElement(taskNamespace + "Settings",
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "MultipleInstancesPolicy", "Parallel"),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "DisallowStartIfOnBatteries", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "StopIfGoingOnBatteries", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "AllowHardTerminate", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "StartWhenAvailable", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "IdleSettings", new XElement(taskNamespace + "StopOnIdleEnd", true),
                                new XElement(taskNamespace + "RestartOnIdle", false)),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "AllowStartOnDemand", true),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Enabled", true), new XElement(taskNamespace + "Hidden", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "RunOnlyIfIdle", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine", true),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "WakeToRun", false),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "ExecutionTimeLimit", "PT0S"),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Priority", 7)),
                        new XElement(taskNamespace + "Actions", new XAttribute("Context", "Author"),
                            new XElement(taskNamespace + "Exec",
                                new XElement(taskNamespace + "Command", Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName),
                                new XElement(taskNamespace + "Arguments",//Arguments ))));
                    string taskString = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null),
                        taskContents).ToString();
                string tempLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),$"{TaskName}.xml");
                    File.WriteAllText(tempLocation, taskString);
/*Run Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "SCHTASKS.exe") with the arguments $"/Create /XML \"{tempLocation}\" /TN {TaskName} /RP * /RU {Environment.UserName}"
I have no time to add that now, in that window you will need to enter your password and you have to be admin*/} 
    public static string DateTimeToWin32Format(DateTime toConvert) =>
                $"{toConvert.Year:0000}-{toConvert.Month:00}-{toConvert.Day:00}T{toConvert.Hour:00}:{toConvert.Minute:00}:{toConvert.Second:00}.{toConvert.Millisecond:000}0000";
```

Please use that function ONLY if your program runs from a protected installation directory.

Comment: can u elaborate

Comment: @user584018 added sample, you only have to change the parameters

Comment: Thanks, it's working

Comment: @user584018 if u need I can give you code for task scheduling too.

Comment: Thanks! I am running with different issue. As per your suggestion I make cmd window as Elevated. Now I need to grab the output, here is the question and some discussion.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464262/c-how-to-capture-root-path-into-a-variable

Comment: if possible, please suggest

Comment: @user584018 mostly done

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tobias... Is there any suggestion for ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464262/c-how-to-capture-root-path-into-a-variable