# How to capture "Root Path" into a variable

Tags: c#, cmd, process, elevated-privileges

I am trying to run `logman.exe` for a elevated `CMD`, for this below code I tried,

```
 var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "cmd /k logman.exe PerfCounterCustom  | findstr \"Root\"",
                Verb = "runas",
                UseShellExecute = true,
            }
        };

        try
        {
            proc.Start();
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully elevated!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

And it's giving error output like,

[image]

`System.InvalidOperationException: StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardOutput()`

2 Questions,

1. when I am running application `exe`, it's showing 2 `CMD` window, the 1st one showing error and 2nd one showing result for argument `"cmd /k logman.exe PerfCounterCustom  | findstr \"Root\""` [Root Path]

how to disable showing both window?

2. Why I am getting this error?

Comment: why not call logman direct? why call cmd.exe ?

Comment: With `UseShellExecute = true` you are running your command with shell (cmd). Your command starts another shell, so you have 2 windows.

Comment: Thanks @Evk, Is there is way to get result of 2nd window (root path) into a variable? I think I need to move this output to first window, which I am not able to do

Comment: I think you don't need any shells at all. Just run logman command alone (without findstr even), without shell, and parse it's redirected output manually.

Comment: My problem, I need to make it elevated to run logman command, that's why I am opening other shell as admin

Comment: Verb = "runas" should made it elevated without cmd

Comment: Please ask two Questions in two separate Questions.

Comment: Ok, I will......

Answer (score 1):

To your 1st Question: In the `ProcessStartInfo` set `WindowStyle` to `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to read the output of the command is to write the output to a text file. Therefore you have to add `>> "[Name or Path of file].txt"` to the end of your command. Then just read the file from C# e.g. with `File.ReadAllLines`.
Two things to consider here:
If you do that often at Runtime and the command delivers huge amounts of text don't write it to an SSD.
Please check that the file is empty / not existing before, because Windows just appends the output to the end of the file. If you run that in multiple threads use a thread identifier in the file name.

Comment: I would like to do at run time and command has only 1 line output. Gr8t idea.

Comment: can I make output to text file without writing it to hard disk, just in memory?

Comment: @user584018 No you cant in any practical way (theoretically you can emulate an drive which contents are stored in memory, there are programs for that out there)

Comment: @user584018 if it helps you have a look at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsinternals/2017/08/25/how-to-create-a-ram-disk-in-windows-server/ or https://github.com/bobvanderlinden/sharpfilesystem

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `RedirectStandardOutput` of the `ProcessStartInfo` to `true` and you have to run `proc.WaitForExit()` before reading the output. 
Please note that this solution causes incompatibilities with running the process as administrator via runas.

Comment: if `UseShellExecute = true,`, then I am not allowed to set `RedirectStandardOutput` to `true`

Comment: getting exception - System.InvalidOperationException: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.

Comment: Yes thats incompatible with starting as administrator, next week I am back home, have some workaround for that,then I will hopefully be able to help u.