# How to run exe as a different user from PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell build script that is run on a build server (GitLab Runner) with admin privileges. I have no control over how this script is started. From this script I need to start an .exe file.

Unfortunately, this executable wants to cache some files in its AppData folder. Because the exe is started as admin, the AppData folder resolves to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\` instead of `C:\Users\User\AppData\` and this causes unexpected behavior.

Is there a way to start the exe as a normal windows user from a script that is started by a system service?

Within the script, I check the user like this:

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169431/62576